# Hyperledger Fabric SOLO network with multiple peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a requirement to setup a poc for hyperledger single organization (SOLO) but they need multiple peers in it (at least two) so that they can show that the block is replicated on both the peers. Is this even possible? If yes would really appreciate if you can point me to any tutorials or something blog where I can get some information about it.

I am using Hyperledger Composer to create the business network. I am following the tutorials from IBM and was able to create a network with one peer (the default setup).

Answer (score 1):

SOLO configuration is a particular configuration of the orderer component, used only in the development phase.

If you are using composer, I suggest to follow the official tutorial for multi-organizations.

Link: [deploy-to-fabric-multi-org](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org)

Since the tutorial is based on the "[Build your first network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html)", you will have a network with:

- Two organizations
- Two peer for each organization (a total of four
  peers)
- One channel

In this way you can deploy your business network to the peers and have the data replicated in each one.